# Цели и особенности [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

1. Что за атрибут `[FromBody]` и какое его назначение?
2. Почему от случая к случаю из-за него не биндится аргумент? Например так (`public List<int> Post(int value, [FromBody]int nam, [FromBody]int sam)`) во всех аргументах нули (даже в value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Атрибут `FromBody` указывает, что параметр метода контроллера должен быть извлечен из данных тела http-запроса и затем десериализован с помощью форматтера входных данных (input formatter). По умолчанию имеется только форматтер JSON.

У этого атрибута есть одна особенность: он может быть применен только **к одному** параметру метода. В этот параметр model binder попытается преобразовать все тело запроса целиком (за такое поведение отвечает параметр `isGreedy` класса [`BindingSource`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/ModelBinding/BindingSource.cs)).

Поэтому в вашем случае придется вынести параметры `nam`, `sam` в отдельный класс:

```
public class PostParams
{
    public int nam { get; set; }
    public int sam { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("{value}")]
public List<int> Post(int value, [FromBody] PostParams prms)
{
    // ...
}
```

Параметр `value`, поскольку это указано в атрибуте `HttpPost`, извлекается из сегмента маршрута. Если в `HttpPost` ничего не указывать, будет анализироваться query string (также можно явно указывать атрибут `FromQuery`).

В старом Web API атрибут `FromBody` также позволял извлечь параметры из данных формы (строка вида `nam=324&sam=4543` в теле запроса), теперь для этого используется отдельный атрибут `FromForm`. Но в отличие от `FromBody` его можно указать несколько раз, для разных параметров.

Comment: Не понял момент с _В этот параметр model binder попытается преобразовать все тело запроса целиком (за такое поведение отвечает параметр isGreedy класса BindingSource)._ Зачем целиком и какие преимущества это дает?
По иронии я уже задал два похожих вопроса, может ответ на этот будет частью какого-то из?
[первый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574146/Почему-может-быть-только-один-параметр-с-frombody)
[второй](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574192/web-api-который-может-обрабатывать-разный-contenttype)

Comment: @Qutrix В старом web api, если параметры надо брать из разных мест - требовалось писать model binder (и возможно, value provider). В Core мне такой кастомизацией пока не приходилось заниматься, но общая концепция не должна была сильно поменяться.