# Почему может быть только один параметр с [FromBody]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Читал про связывание моделей в asp.net и наткнулся на такой обзац:

> Только одному параметру в методе действия можно добавить [FromBody]. ASP.NET Core MVC передает ответственность за прочтение потока запроса форматтеру. После прочтения потока он не может снова прочесть поток для связывания других параметров [FromBody].

[Ссылка на статью](https://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/mvc/models/model-binding.html)

Почему так? И допустим я на сервер отправляю такую строчку: `{"value":"1"}` - мне для нее создавать отдельный класс, чтоб принять ее? Потому что `public void Post([FromBody]int value)` не работает

Comment: Да, создавать отдельный класс. Или пишите полностью свой биндер, который будет разбирать запрос пользуясь своими же атрибутами.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том что, что тело запроса может быть сохранено в небуферизованный поток, который можно прочитать только один раз.

[Вот тут всё детально описано](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг случается (непонятно как и зачем) необходимость принять в POST запросе 2 параметра, то проще на стороне клиента "пихать" свои объекты в какой то один объект, далее на контроллере создавать принимаемый параметр типа dynamic и уже на контроллере разбивать его на 2 или более объекта... Ну или создать модель =)

Comment: "Если вдруг случается (непонятно как и зачем) необходимость принять в POST запросе 2 параметра" - в смысле как и зачем? Это же вроде обычная практика, не?

Comment: Нет, всегда хватает одной модели (одного объекта)