# Web Api, который может обрабатывать разный ContentType

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Как мне написать метод, который мог бы одинаково хорошо обрабатывать как `Content-Type: application/json`, так и `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Ведь в первом случае мне надо ставить атрибут `[FromBody]` для параметра, но при втором случае (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) он вернет мне `415 Unsupported Media Type`, если оставить `[FromBody]`

Comment: Работаю с "application/json" и без FromBody. Ну ещё как вариант перегрузка методов!

Comment: @gromanev, да, я уже понял что вопрос некорректный, потому что мой вопрос касается исключительно asp.net core, в web api все работает как надо. А можно подробнее про перегрузку методов?

Comment: ну перегрузка метода, это создание ещё одного метода, выполняющую близкую цель к перегружаемому, с сохранением названия метода, сохранением возвращаемого типа, но сменой сигнатуры параметров

Comment: @gromanev, в данном случае это не подходит:
1) с добавление атрибута сигнатура параметров не изменится
2) я так поломаю селектор (будет два метода помеченных атрибутом HttpPost, что вызовет неоднозначность при выборе конкретного экшна)

Comment: раскрою один секрет, что REST не заключается в том что бы следовать всем правилам построения CRUD-приложения           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi2",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            ); Вам в помощь!

Comment: @gromanev, не заключается, но возможно, и этой возможностью хотелось бы пользоваться, да и "1) с добавлением атрибута сигнатура параметров не изменится"