# VueJs + Axios+ Asp.Net MVC 5 Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-mvc

В контроллере метод (указывать [FromBody] тоже пробовал, не помогло):

```
[HttpPost]
public string RegUser(DTM.UserRegDataRequestModel Model)
```

Параметр это класс имеющий 3 строковых свойства.

На VueJS заполняются поля и передаются через Axios на контроллер:

```
axios.post(URL, RequestData)
```

При попытке сделать запрос Axios ошибка:

> 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Параметр "RequestData" имеет точно такую же структуру, с такими же полями, что и ожидаемый на контроллере класс. Пробовал переводить в строку *JSON.stringify(RequestData)*, на случай если MVC ожидает строковый JSON для разбора и соотнесения с классом.. Но ничего не получается.

Что-то похожее делал когда-то на Net.Core и там без всяких преобразований дополнительных, контроллер спокойно получал объекты из Vue через Axios. Т.е. с аттрибутом [FromBody] преобразовывал полученный параметр в класс.
А в данном случае обрывается даже не начав выполнять метод, просто сервер отклоняется с ошибкой.

**Что не так ? Как подружить это дело ?**

Дополнения:

CORS на ASP.Net:

```
var CorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
config.EnableCors(CorsAttribute);
```

Axios на VueJs:

```
var AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BaseUrl,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
});
```

Comment: Поставьте fiddler и покажите заголовки запроса на ваш экшн. У вас там `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Или у вас `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52674978/5752652

Comment: @AK, дополнил вопрос новой информацией. Content-Type: application/json.

Comment: POST /api/auth/RegUser HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

"Message":"Запрос содержит основной текст сущности, но заголовок Content-Type отсутствует. Для данного ресурса не поддерживается выводимый тип мультимедиа \"application/octet-stream\".","ExceptionMessage":"Нет доступных MediaTypeFormatter для чтения объекта типа \"UserRegDataRequestModel\" с содержимым типа мультимедиа \"application/octet-stream\"."

Comment: @AK, решил поэксперементировать с вашей наводкой на проблемное место. Оказалось если оставить только ""Content-Type": "application/json", то ASP.NET все прекрасно понимает и преобразовывает в модель. А если добавить там что-то еще (как в описании задачи или часть какую-то из того), то он тут же перестает понимать. Может есть совет или инструкция как это нормально настраивать ?
Везде пишут указывать можно "кучу всего", но куча эта потом сама себя не понимает )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У майкрософт вполне чётко и наглядно описано в документации, как должна работать привязка к модели:

- [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) - для классической версии
- [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) - для core 2.1

Они немного отличаются в ньюансах - так в классической версии были атрибуты FromUri, FromBody, в core это FromQuery, FromBody.

Также можете посмотреть [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/2.6.php) (classic) и [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/8.5.php) (core) небольшие эксперименты с отдельными типами привязок. А, и [вот ещё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573840/213987) в закладках завалялось.

Я для себя при изучении темы также ставил множество мини-экспериментов, чтобы разобраться как это работает. Делается весьма просто: создаётся небольшой контроллер с одним методом:

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody] My value)
    {
    }
}

public class My
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

И "обстреливается" различными запросами (я это делаю подготовив небольшой скрипт в linqpad, вы можете использовать отдельный проект в студии). Основа скрипта:

```
public class WebRequestHelper
{
    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }

    public async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string jsonString)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");     
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Примеры запросов для образца:

```
// Post samples as webform

unit.PostFormAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/my", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "value", "5" }, })
    .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value=5.

unit.PostFormAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/postform", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "value1", "5" }, { "value2", "7" }, })
    .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value1=5, value2=7.

// Post samples as json

unit.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/postjson", "\"asdf\"")
    .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value=asdf.

unit.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/asdf", "{\"Value1\":5,\"Value2\":\"asdf\"}")
    .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value1=5, value2=asdf.

unit.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/asdf", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Value1 = 1, Value2 = "asdf", }))
    .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value1=5, value2=asdf.
```

(Лично я как-то <s>протупил</s> очень много времени потратил времени на то, чтобы понять, какой json нужно передать чтобы появилась просто строка - теперь я крепко запомнил: просто `asdf`, без всяких `{}`)

По теме передачи форм (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`) почитайте например эти ссылки:

- [Understanding HTML Form Encoding: URL Encoded and Multipart Forms](https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa)
- [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/5752652)

Обратите внимание. Для отправки веб-форм мы из C# используем dictionary, для отправки json в теле запроса используем указание Content-type: application/json - в документации майкрософт явно сказано, что выбор места привязки определяется именно через контент-тайп и больше ничем.

> [FromBody]: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the
>   request body. The formatter is selected **based on content type** of
>   the request.

(Выделение моё, цитирую английскую версию - там более явно видно, чем в переводе.)

Так что можете не читать никакие шаманские статьи, не наворачивать ничего дополнительного: FromBody рулится через указание Content-type, точка. И майкрософт в этом плане полне придерживается рекомендаций w3c - также поступает и другое правильное ПО, а не ставит какие-то свои костыли.

По теме конкретно вашего вопроса (в контексте именно vue.js и Axios) я вам приводил в комментариях ссылку продублирую ещё раз: [Vue.js and .NET WEBAPI2 POST from Axios 405 or 415 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52674978/5752652)