# Как правильно написать post-запрос на сервер?

Tags: vue.js, post, vuex

У меня есть данные в store - массив терминов.

Как написать post-запрос к серверу для синхронизации терминов (в методе компонента Vue), когда моковые данные выключены.

P.S. Как можно использовать Axios?

```
  methods: {
    onTermCreate(newTerm) {
      const actionName = this.getModuleActionName('term', ACTIONS_NAMES.CREATE_TERM);
      this.$store.dispatch(actionName, newTerm).then(() => {
        // TODO add post request to sync terms state with server, then reset form //
        this.showPostRequestData();
        this.resetForm();
      })
    },

    addNewDataToExistingTerm(existingTerm, newTerm) {
      existingTerm.parents.push(newTerm);
      const actionName = this.getModuleActionName('term', ACTIONS_NAMES.UPDATE_TERM);
      this.$store.dispatch(actionName, existingTerm).then(() => {
        // TODO add post request to sync terms state with server, then reset form //
        this.showPostRequestData();
        this.resetForm();
      })
    }
 }
```

Comment: А что у вас в качестве бекенда, который будет принимать post-запрос? Или точнее, какие именно параметры и [как](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922057/213987) он будет читать из post? (json параметры или form-value?)

Comment: @AK json-параметры