# Не передается byte[] в controller с помощью HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

Когда пытаюсь передать через MultipartFormDataContent 2 значения, передается только String, а массив байтов передается пустым.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var stringContent = new StringContent("1");
var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(stringContent, "id");
content.Add(binaryContent, "content");

var result = await client.PostAsync("/Incoming", content);
string resultContent1 = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(resultContent1);
```

Controller:

```
[Route("Incoming")]
public async Task<string> PostIncomingData(SomePostRequest requestData)
{
    return Convert.ToString(requestData.Id)+ Convert.ToString(requestData.Content);
}
```

SomePostRequest.cs

```
public sealed class SomePostRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Запрос наполовину выполняется, он выводит мне id, но content не выводит. Просто ничего вместо content.

Перерыл множество форумов, в том числе и англоязычных, все там используют либо WebApi на сервере, либо старый WebClient на клиенте.... Я вроде переделал под Asp.Net Core MVC, но работать это все не хочет. Может есть какой-либо более простой способ передать массив байтов на контроллер? Я хочу именно используя HttpClient.

Comment: О, тут не одна ошибка а сразу несколько, причём идеологических и нужно определиться чего именно вы хотите. Если Json - то у вас не получится передать byte array, вам нужно его в base64 что ли... Если хотите передавать через MultipartFormData -- то тогда не надо ставить хедер json. Тут как бы то надо сначала понять, какой из двух вариантов ответа вам ближе.

Comment: `binaryContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Почему не в ответ? Автор похоже как раз на MultipartForm хочет ответ.

Comment: @AK - я не уверен, какие именно заголовки ставить. Пусть автор попробует.

Comment: Можно вообще убрать эту строку - [должно нормально отработать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/922388/213987).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я уже и добавлял эту строчку, и удалял.

Comment: Мне будет достаточно отправлять массив байтов, без id. А вот про json может сработать. Если вы напишите в ответ как, я приму за ответ и это :) Главное чтобы на выходе был массив байтов.

Comment: Она точно не нужна. При передаче json он передаётся в body и используется биндинг FromBody (в коре точно, а что раньше было уже не помню), но когда используется multipart запрос там никакого боди.

Comment: А у вас точно классический asp.net mvc, не core?

Comment: Как раз core...

Comment: какой? 2.2, 3.0?

Comment: asp.net core 3.1

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113587/discussion-between-villyfiki-and-a-k).